# Getting discord.py display names

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a bot before the username update, and I decided to start working on it again. However, `author.display_name` gets the user's username, not display name.[If you don't know what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSnxj.png)

If you know a solution, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Links are not preferred. Please include the relevant code as well.